# Calculate mode of a column in Pandas using other column with same row values

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have following `df` -

```
id            score
222.0         0.0           
222.0         0.0           
222.0         1.0           
222.0         0.0           
222.0         1.0           
222.0         1.0           
222.0         1.0           
222.0         0.0           
222.0         1.0           
222.0        -1.0           
416.0         0.0           
416.0         0.0           
416.0         2.0           
416.0         0.0           
416.0         1.0           
416.0         0.0           
416.0         1.0           
416.0         1.0           
416.0         0.0           
416.0         0.0           
895.0         1.0           
895.0         0.0           
895.0         0.0           
895.0         0.0           
895.0         0.0           
895.0         0.0           
895.0         0.0           
895.0         0.0           
895.0         0.0           
895.0         0.0
```

I want to calculate mode for same value of `id` for `score` column. Something Like this-

```
id            score
222.0         1.0           
416.0         0.0           
895.0         0.0
```

My tried like this-

```
df['score'] = df.mode()['score']
```

But I am getting following output -

```
id            score
222.0         0.0           
222.0         NaN           
222.0         NaN           
222.0         NaN           
222.0         NaN           
222.0         NaN           
222.0         NaN           
222.0         NaN           
222.0         NaN           
222.0         NaN           
416.0         NaN           
416.0         NaN           
416.0         NaN          
416.0         NaN           
416.0         NaN           
416.0         NaN           
416.0         NaN           
416.0         NaN           
416.0         NaN           
416.0         NaN           
895.0         NaN           
895.0         NaN           
895.0         NaN           
895.0         NaN           
895.0         NaN           
895.0         NaN           
895.0         NaN           
895.0         NaN           
895.0         NaN           
895.0         NaN
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group the scores by ids, and apply mode to each:

```
>>> df.score.groupby(df['id']).apply(lambda g: g.mode()).reset_index()[['id', 'score']]
      id    score
0   222.0   1.0
1   416.0   0.0
2   895.0   0.0
```

Comment: Thanks I was not doing groupby.

Comment: `df.score.groupby(df['id']).agg(lambda g: g.mode()).reset_index()` would do?

Answer (score 1):

You could also use

```
In [79]: df.groupby('id').agg({'score': lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0]}).reset_index()
Out[79]:
      id  score
0  222.0    1.0
1  416.0    0.0
2  895.0    0.0
```

Or, use

```
In [80]: from scipy.stats.mstats import mode

In [81]: df.groupby('id').agg({'score': lambda x: mode(x)[0]}).reset_index()
Out[81]:
      id  score
0  222.0    1.0
1  416.0    0.0
2  895.0    0.0
```

Comment: Very nice <filler>